# can anyone explain how can we make a universal software updates checker?

Tags: web-applications

I need only all possible suggestions preferably using java or python, I tried doing it by creating a database of all possible software.
But it was not an efficient solution.
any suggestions?

Comment: Which OS? Can you elaborate on what *universal software update checker means* (features, use case)?

Comment: universal software update checker means an app which will run  on Windows PC and upon querying the name of the software_version it will return all the possible upgrades for a software

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest to use your OS's package manager and distribution format (i.e: apt and deb packages on Debian/Ubuntu; yum and rpm on RedHat/CentOS). Adding a private repository if needed.

If you are using Windows or OSX you could use some of the de-facto package managers like [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) and Brew.

For instance, [Chocolatey Package Updater](https://chocolatey.org/packages/ChocolateyPackageUpdater) is a solution to update packages automatically.